# Android: How to configure a loading screen with background color and centered image

Tags: android, flutter

So, I've almost finished my Android app using Flutter, and now I've just created the icons using Android studio tools (right click on "res" folder -> new -> image asset...).
So far so good, but now I'm having an hard time trying to figure out how to put the app icon in the loading screen.
What I did so far is:

Creating a styles.xml under res/values:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <style name="LaunchTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar">
        <item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/launch_background</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

Creating a launch_background.xml in res/drawable:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:gravity="center">
    <item android:drawable="@android:color/holo_green_light" />
    <item>
        <bitmap android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher" />
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

but the asset `@mipmap/ic_launcher` is not resolved... I have no idea how to specify it correctly!

In AndroidManifest.xml I've defined the theme as `android:theme="@style/LaunchTheme"` and the icon as `android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"`... and since the icon is correctly used by the app once installed, I don't get why in the manisfest is resolved and in the other file is not... what I'm supposed to do?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a dev dependencies package: https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_native_splash

Add on `pubspec.yaml`

```
dev_dependencies:
   flutter_native_splash: ^0.1.9
```

declare your icon launcher and color

```
flutter_native_splash:
  image: 'assets/ic_launcher.png'
  color: "#36133d"
```

and them run:

1. `flutter pub get`
2. `flutter pub run flutter_native_splash:create`

Answer (score 0):

I like the simplicity of Eric's response, additionally, there is thorough documentation on the flutter.dev website on how to do this without the additional package.

https://flutter.dev/docs/development/ui/splash-screen/android-splash-screen

Answer (score 0):

So, after several attempts I've solved in by using the following configurations:

**styles.xml**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <style name="LaunchTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme.Light.NoTitleBar">
        <item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/launch_background</item>
    </style>
    <color name="white">#FFFFFF</color>
</resources>
```

**launch_background.xml**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:gravity="center">
    <item android:drawable="@color/white" />
    <item
        android:width="400px"
        android:height="400px"
        android:drawable="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:gravity="center" />
</layer-list>
```

The relevant difference is that I'm now using a drawable for the logo instead of a bitmap. Currently, it works perfectly in release mode (`flutter clean && flutter run --release`), even though in debug mode a black screen is visible for few milliseconds before the main Flutter widget is actually rendered.